# Implement Laravel Self-hosted Websocket and Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, websocket

I am trying to make connections to Laravel self-hosted Websocket (using Laravel echo settings), and Flutter app (also using web_socket_channel). So I have a main class BaseWebSocketService:

```
    class BaseWebSocketService {
  late IOWebSocketChannel? _channel;
  IOWebSocketChannel? myChannel;

  late Timer _pingTimer;
  final ErrorProvider _errorNotifier = ErrorProvider();
  final serverUrl = CallApi.appSocket;

  BaseWebSocketService() {
    initializeWebSocket();
  }

  Future<void> initializeWebSocket() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      _errorNotifier.setError('No internet connection');
      // Retry logic can be implemented here
      return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), initializeWebSocket);
    }

    try {
      final httpClient = HttpClient();
      httpClient.badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => true;

      final headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${await Auth.getUserToken()}'};
      _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        Uri.parse(serverUrl),
        headers: headers,
        customClient: httpClient,
      );

      // set value
      myChannel = _channel;

      // Ensure _channel is initialized before using it
      await _channel!.stream
          .toList(); // This line waits for the stream to be fully listened to

      _pingTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: pingInterval), (_) {
        try {
          sendPing();
        } catch (e) {
          _errorNotifier.setError('Error sending ping: $e');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      _errorNotifier.setError('WebSocket connection error: $e');
      // Retry logic can be implemented here
      return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), initializeWebSocket);
    }
  }

  // Constants
  static const int pingInterval = 30;
  static const String pingEvent = '{"event": "ping"}';

  // Protected getter for _channel
  Future<IOWebSocketChannel?> get protectedChannel async {
    // Make sure _channel is initialized before returning
    await initializeWebSocket();
    return _channel;
  }

  void sendPing() {
    try {
      myChannel?.sink.add(pingEvent);
    } catch (e) {
      _errorNotifier.setError('Error sending ping: $e');
    }
  }

  void closeWebSocket() {
    try {
      _pingTimer.cancel();
      _channel!.sink.close();
    } catch (e) {
      _errorNotifier.setError('Error closing WebSocket: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> authenticate(socketId) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      final payload = {
        'event': 'pusher:subscribe',
        'data': {
          'channel': '', // Pass channelName as a parameter
          'auth': {
            'headers': {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ${await Auth.getUserToken()}',
            }
          }
        }
      };
      _channel?.sink.add(jsonEncode(payload));

      response = await CallApi().broadcastAuth({
        'socket_id': socketId,
        'channel_name': '', // Pass channelName as a parameter
        'encrypted': true,
        'forceTLS': true,
        'key': '',
        'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss'],
        'namespace': "App.Events",
        'wsHost': xxxxxxxDomainName.xxxxxxxCom,
        'wsPort': 6001,
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Authentication successful
        print('Authentication successful');
      } else if (response.statusCode == 302) {
        // Authentication failed
        _errorNotifier.setError('Authentication failed');
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      // Handle authentication error
      _errorNotifier.setError('Authentication error: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example to extend BaseWebSocketService to use for a presence channel:

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:xxxx/http/websockets/base_websocket_service.dart';

class EchoPresenceChannel extends BaseWebSocketService {
  var _socketChannel;
  String? _channelName;
  String? _socketId;

  ///On joining the channel:
  ///authenticate the user
  ///@param channel name
  ///@param event name
  Future<void> joining(String channelName, String eventName) async {
    _channelName = channelName;
    final payload = {
      'event': 'pusher:subscribe',
      'data': {'channel': channelName},
    };

    _socketChannel = await protectedChannel;

    // Subscribe to the channel
    print('pusher:subscribe.......');
    // Listening
    listening(eventName);
    _socketChannel?.stream.listen(
      _handleSubscriptionEvent,
      onError: _handleError,
    );
    _socketChannel?.sink.add(jsonEncode(payload));
  }

  ///Unscribe to the channel
  Future<void> leaveChannel() async {
    final payload = {
      'event': 'pusher:unsubscribe',
      'data': {'channel': _channelName},
    };
    myChannel?.sink.add(jsonEncode(payload));
  }

  Future<List<String>> members() async {
    final payload = {
      'event': 'pusher:members',
      'data': {'channel': _channelName},
    };
    myChannel?.sink.add(jsonEncode(payload));

    final response = await myChannel!.stream.first;
    final responseData = jsonDecode(response);

    final members = List<String>.from(responseData['data']);
    return members;
  }

  //When auth leave the channel
  void leaving(void Function(String) onMemberLeave) {
    myChannel?.stream.listen(
      (dynamic res) {
        final myData = res;
        Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(myData);

        if (jsonData.containsKey('event') && jsonData.containsKey('data')) {
          var event = jsonData['event'];
          var data = jsonDecode(jsonData['data']);
          _handleMemberRemoved(event, data, onMemberLeave);
        }
      },
      onError: _handleError,
    );
  }

  Future<void> listening(String eventName) async {
    myChannel?.stream.listen(
      (dynamic res) async {
        final myData = res;
        Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(myData);

        if (jsonData.containsKey('event') && jsonData.containsKey('data')) {
          var event = jsonData['event'];
          var data = jsonDecode(jsonData['data']);
          _handlePresenceEvents(event, data, eventName);
        }
      },
      onError: _handleError,
    );
  }

  void _handleSubscriptionEvent(dynamic res) {
    final myData = res;
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(myData);

    if (jsonData.containsKey('event') && jsonData.containsKey('data')) {
      var event = jsonData['event'];
      var data = jsonDecode(jsonData['data']);

      switch (event) {
        case 'pusher:subscription_succeeded':
          _handleSubscriptionSucceeded(data);
          break;
        // Add more cases for other presence events if needed
      }
    }
  }

  void _handleError(dynamic error) {
    print('Error in stream: $error');
    // Handle errors in the stream
  }

  void _handleSubscriptionSucceeded(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    print('Subscription succeeded for channel: $_channelName');
    _socketId = data['socket_id'];
    print('Socket ID: $_socketId');
  }

  void _handleMemberRemoved(String event, Map<String, dynamic> data,
      void Function(String) onMemberLeave) {
    switch (event) {
      case 'pusher:member_removed':
        final memberId = data['user_id'];
        onMemberLeave(memberId);
        break;
      // Add more cases for other presence events if needed
    }
  }

  void _handlePresenceEvents(
      String event, Map<String, dynamic> data, String eventName) {
    switch (event) {
      case 'pusher:connection_established':
        _socketId = data['socket_id'];
        authenticate(_socketId);
        print(event);
        break;
      case 'pusher:subscription_succeeded':
        // Handle successful subscription
        print(event);
        break;
      case 'pusher:member_added':
        // Handle a user joining the presence channel
        print(event);
        break;
      case 'pusher:member_removed':
        // Handle a user leaving the presence channel
        print(event);
        break;
      default:
        if (event == 'App\\Events\\$eventName') {
          // Handle your custom event
          print(event);
        }
        // Add more cases for other events if needed
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Example: use a presence channel anywhere in my application:

```
var presenceChannel = EchoPresenceChannel();
      // join a presence channel
      await presenceChannel.joining(
          'presence-user-status-connected.1', 'UserStatusChangedEvent');

      // list of all members in a presence channel
      presenceChannel.members();

      // Leaving a presence channel
      presenceChannel.leaving((member) {
        // member is has left
      });
```

Comment: what is the question ?